# Expected Value of $Y/X$

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

Consider two random variable, $X$ and $Y$ such that $E(Y\mid X)=0.5X$ and $E(Y) = 20$ and $E(X) = 10$. Compute $E(Y/X)$.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname E}$
\begin{align}
& \e\left( \frac Y X \right) = \e\left( \e\left( \frac Y X \,\Big\vert\, X \right) \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \e\left( \frac 1 X \e (Y\mid X) \right)  = \e\left( \frac 1 X (0.5 X) \right) =0.5.
\end{align}

Comment: There seems to be a problem with OP's question because in the same way, $\text{E}[Y]=\text{E}[\text{E}[Y|X]]=\text{E}[0.5X]=0.5\text{E}[X]$ which seems to contradict that $\text{E}[Y]=20$ and $\text{E}[X]=10$.